# $_POST variable only returning values for some fields, but not all

Tags: html, forms, post, textinput

Edited for my stupidity:

I have a simple html form, with basic select, text, and textarea inputs.  After submission, the form is returning blanks for some fields, but not all.  Below is the form:

```
<form action='?action=createDigitalJob' method='post'>
    <table width='100%'>
        <tr>
            <th align='left'>Job Type</th>
            <td>
                <select id='jobTypeID' name='jobType' style='width:250px;' onchange=\"digitalJobToggle('jobTypeID')\">
                    <option value='0'>Count Type&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
                    <option value='wu'>Web Update&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
                    <option value='purl'>PURL&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
                    <option value='furl'>FURL&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
                    <option value='gurl'>GURL&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
                    <option value='domain'>Domain Purchase&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
                    <option value='eblast'>E-Blast&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
                    <option value='tdm'>TDM&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
                    <option value='crm'>ORM&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align='left'>Urgent</th>
            <td>
                <select name='isUrgent'>
                    <option value='No'>No&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
                    <option value='Yes'>Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='wu' style='display:none'>
            <td colspan='2'>
                <table class='plain'>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Webpage Address</td>
                        <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"webpageAddress\" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign='top'>Current Text</td>
                        <td><textarea name='currentText' style='width:500px; height:250px;' placeholder='Current Text' ></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign='top'>New Text</td>
                        <td><textarea name='newText' style='width:500px; height:250px;' placeholder='New Text Text' ></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Copy Proofed?</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name='copyProofed'>
                                <option value='No'>No&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value='Yes'>Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='submitRow' style='display:none'>
            <td colspan='2'>
                <input type='hidden' name='step' value='2' />
                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type='button' value='Cancel' onclick='javascript:history.go(-1);' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

after submitting the form, I can do a print_r($_POST) and receive the following:

> Array ( [jobType] => wu [isUrgent] => Yes [webpageAddress] => [currentText] => 1 [newText] => [copyProofed] => No [creativeComplete] => No [jobNumber] => [phoneVerified] => No [leadEmail] => [variables] => [pincodes] => No [webpageAddress2] => [eblastType] => Digital [subjectLine] => [copyApproved] => No [dueDate_Month] => 1 [dueDate_Day] => 1 [dueDate_Year] => 2012 [notes] => 41 [step] => 2 [submit] => Submit )

And if I a var_dump($_POST), I get this:

> array
>     'jobType' => string 'wu' (length=2)
>     'isUrgent' => string 'Yes' (length=3)
>     'webpageAddress' => string '' (length=0)
>     'currentText' => string '1' (length=1)
>     'newText' => string '' (length=0)
>     'copyProofed' => string 'No' (length=2)
>     'creativeComplete' => string 'No' (length=2)
>     'jobNumber' => string '' (length=0)
>     'phoneVerified' => string 'No' (length=2)
>     'leadEmail' => string '' (length=0)
>     'variables' => string '' (length=0)
>     'pincodes' => string 'No' (length=2)
>     'webpageAddress2' => string '' (length=0)
>     'eblastType' => string 'Digital' (length=7)
>     'subjectLine' => string '' (length=0)
>     'copyApproved' => string 'No' (length=2)
>     'dueDate_Month' => string '1' (length=1)
>     'dueDate_Day' => string '1' (length=1)
>     'dueDate_Year' => string '2012' (length=4)
>     'notes' => string '41' (length=2)
>     'step' => string '2' (length=1)
>     'submit' => string 'Submit' (length=6)

Both types of $_POST dump are showing an empty value for webpageAddress and newText even though I entered data for them before hitting submit.  Anybody know why that data i entered wouldn't be available in the $_POST dump?

Anybody know what's going on here?

Comment: Var dump has this:  `'currentText' => string '1' (length=1)`

Comment: right, for current text... but not webpageaddress: 'webpageAddress' => string '' (length=0).  Some of the fields are working, others are not.  That's why I'm so confused.

Comment: Quite and in your print_r: 'webpageAddress' => {Blank}` or a 0 length string. I'm not sure what you're question is. There is something wrong with your PHP logic.

Comment: Your HTML hurts my eyes.

Comment: if i do a echo $_POST['webpageAddress'] i get ''.  Even though it shows up in the print_r($_POST);

Comment: It shows up because the POST request has sent a key value pair. 'wepageAddress' = '';

Comment: But I entered a value for it on the form.  Then i hit submit, and the value changes to ''

Comment: @Brds: webpageAddress seems to be working fine too... `[webpageAddress] => ` in the first and  `'webpageAddress' => string '' (length=0)` in the latter. Note that in the first the empty string is not particularly obvious but its what I'd expect...

Comment: webpageAddress] => [currentText] => 1 in print_r and 'webpageAddress' => string '' (length=0) in var_dump.  One is givng me back the value I entered, and the other isn't.

Comment: @Brds: So is the question actually why do values that I enter on an web page not come through to the code? Because at the moment your question looks like it is about a difference in content of `print_r($_POST)` and `var_dump($_POST)`...

Comment: in your question the output of `var_dump` and `print_r` **matches** ... whats the problem ?

Comment: They're not matching though.  One is showing me "1" as a value and the other is showing me ''

Comment: `webpageAddress] => [currentText] => 1` is two separate statements. The `currentText` refers to the currentText field and suggests that you entered 1 into that field. The `webpageAddress` refers to the field of the same name and is putting in a blank string which may be confusing you into thinking it is pointing to the `[CurrentText]` but that is actually the start of the next field's content declaration.

Comment: Ugh... I'm an idiot!  Okay, so now my question is ... why won't the form pass my value for "webpageAddress"?

Comment: @Brds: I'd suggets using something like fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to intercept your traffic so you can analyse exactly what is going back and forth or something else similar. From your html I can see no reason why it wouldn't be passing through that content so chcecking the HTTP communication will allow you to see all the form values passed. Please do check that you have definitely put a value into that field though and that you aren't getting fields confused...

Answer (score 1):

`[currentText] => 1` (output from `print_r`)

and

`'currentText' => string '1' (length=1)` (output from `var_dump`)

are the same .... ie a value of `1` .. `var_dump` shows the type of the field (`string` in this case) where as `print_r` does not ... from the manual :

`print_r`

> displays information about a variable in a way that's readable by humans

where as `var_dump`

> displays structured information about one or more expressions that includes its type and value. Arrays and objects are explored recursively with values indented to show structure.

Where there is no value `print_r` with display this :

`[webpageAddress] =>`

and `var_dump` will display this

`'webpageAddress' => string '' (length=0)`

Comment: Right, but i'm getting the output of "1" for the print_r, but not in the var dump.

Comment: @Brds you are ... `string '1'` shows the type and value .. the value is in `''` (quotes)

Comment: print_r is giving me a value of "1"... var_dump (or $var = $_POST['webpageAddress']; echo $var;) is giving me '';

Comment: @Brds no its not - in `print_r` and `var_dump` output the value for `webpageAddress` is `''` ie empty ...

Comment: [webpageAddress] => [currentText] => 1 for print_r and  'webpageAddress' => string '' (length=0) for var_dump....

Comment: @Brds `[webpageAddress]` is one field and `[currentText]` is another ... the value for `[webpageAddress]` is empty and the `[currentText]` value is `1`

Comment: I'm an idiot... i see they're both returning an empty value now.  But now my question is, why isn't the form carrying over the value i entered for "webpageAddress"?

Comment: @Brds there doesn't seem to be any obvious problem - check the output is as expected - ie the quotes are in the correct place - check error log for errors too ...

Answer (score 0):

some variables in the output do not appear in the html code (webpageAddress2, eblastType, subjectLine) . In the case of "webpageAddress" did you try remove the escape characters?  what happens  if you remove escapes( \ ) from quotes ( " )?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a table inside of a table. I would never build a form using tables. Divs or a list with CSS adjusting the size and location is a much easier and cleaner system to manage and debug.

Also to save yourself the headache of escaping every " with \" try saving the form like this

```
$form = <<<EOT
<form html here>
EOT;
```